# ImportError: No Module named 'mt_exceptions' when using Mingus library

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror

Forgive my ignorance in advance, I am very new to python. I am trying to use a python 3 version (https://code.google.com/r/artdent-mingus-python3/) of the Mingus library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mingus/) in 3.4.2. When trying to use the note module, I keep getting the ImportError listed in the title.

Based on my research on similar ImportError questions, I have tried the following things:
-I made sure there was a mt_exceptions.py file in the relevant directory
-I made sure each mingus directory in the site-packages directory has **init**.py file
-I deleted the .pyc files in the mingus directory

Any pointers on what I might try next?

Comment: Check where the package is installed and make sure install location is in sys.path or PYTHONPATH

Comment: When I try:
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
output includes:
['C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
Which is where the package is installed.

Comment: Can you post the the directory tree contents and show where mt_exception is located.

Comment: 'Python34  
|  
+--Lib  
|  |  
   +--site-packages  
   |  |  
      +--mingus  
      |  |  
         +--core  
         |  |  
            +--mt_exceptions.py  
     |  '

Comment: so did you try import mingus.core.mt_exceptions

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the problem by manually entering in "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\mingus\core" and editing the file (In my case, I had to edit notes.py from *"from mt_exceptions import NoteFormatError, RangeError, FormatError"* to *"from mingus.core.mt_exceptions import NoteFormatError, RangeError, FormatError"*, and then I got a typical Python 2.x running on 3.x dict error. So that's the problem!

Solution: Use Python 2.x, [or update the whole schmere to 3.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) (That's what I'm doing).

[As you can see here](http://python3porting.com/problems.html), Python 3.x has changed the import syntax a bit, and that's **exactly** what's happening. I had to run 2to3 through all the mingus source code and fix the imports manually from all files (Basically, porting the whole thing to Python 3.x).

Comment: what is 'schmere' please?

Answer (score 0):

Ericson Willians is correct. I fixed this with 2to3.py. I installed Mingus with:

```
pip install mingus
```

Then, I navigated to the directory where pip installed Mingus:

```
pip show mingus
```

In the top directory for Mingus (~/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/mingus)

I ran:

```
~/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Tools/scripts/2to3.py -w .
```

This has fixed Mingus for me, so far.