# Mingus/lilypond on python

Tags: python, lilypond

I can import mingus but sublibraries such as mingus.extra.lilypond give me an error:

```
 import mingus.core.notes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    import mingus.core.notes
  File "C:\Users\PharaohZz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mingus\core\notes.py", line 29, in <module>
    from mt_exceptions import NoteFormatError, RangeError, FormatError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mt_exceptions'
```

or

```
import mingus.extra.lilypond

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import mingus.extra.lilypond
  File "C:\Users\PharaohZz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mingus\extra\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import lilypond
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lilypond'
```

Comment: For the first error, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26984731/4039050) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by first uninstalling mingus (`pip uninstall mingus`).
Then build the library from it's source. To do this:

1. Download the files from git hub using the command `git clone https://github.com/bspaans/python-mingus` .
2. Enter the directory using `cd python-mingus`.
3. Finally install it using the command `python setup.py install`.
   This fixed the problem for me.